# Shuffling a list using random-fu shuffle, doing an operation on a list and displaying result in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, shuffle

My goal is to get a list of **N** random items taken from an input list and see the result in GHCI. I decided to shuffle the input list, then take the first **N** elements from it (i.e. slice first elements). I am using `shuffle` function from random-fu module [Data.Random.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7/docs/Data-Random-List.html).

Here's the code I currently have and at least it can be compiled

```
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.List

rndSelect :: [a] -> Int -> RVar [a]
rndSelect l n
  = do 
       l' <- shuffle l;
       return $ take n l'
```

But when I run `rndSelect "abcdefg" 3` in GHCI prompt, I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (RVar [Char]))
        arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I think I know what it means. `RVar` doesn't derive `Show`. I guess I should modify my function so that it gets shuffled `RVar[a]` and then somehow take a list of the first *N* elements and convert it to IO action.

Here's one of my failed attempts:

```
rndSelect :: [a] -> Int -> IO ()
rndSelect l n
  = do 
       l' <- shuffle l;
       l'' <- take n l'
       s <- runRVar l'' StdRandom
       putStrLn s
```

I know, that it is messed up and raises errors on top of errors. I am beginner in Monads, "do" blocks and things like that in Haskell

I would be glad if someone help me to fix my approach, but if you know alternative way to achieve my goal, I will be happy to see it as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: How many elements would you expect `rndSelect "abcdefg"` to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rndSelect :: [a] -> Int -> RVar [a]` is perfectly fine, but it should be obvious that the resulting `RVar [a]` can't really be shown. After all, this is a *probability distribution*. Such distributions “contain” in general infinitely many possible outcomes. All you can hope to do is to show *samples* from the distribution. Since GHCi allows you to do IO, it's easy to obtain samples right there:

```
*Main> sample $ rndSelect "abcdefg" 3
"def"
*Main> sample $ rndSelect "abcdefg" 3
"ecb"
*Main> sample $ rndSelect "abcdefg" 3
"fbc"
*Main> :m +Control.Monad
*Main Control.Monad> sample . replicateM 20 $ rndSelect "abcdefg" 3
["gef","adf","cga","bfd","eab","bgd","gdf","abg","egc","bda","ceb","fbd","agb","egc","acb","bga","gbd","edb","egb","egd"]
```

Comment: The docs state `runRVar x StdRandom === sampleRVar` (I guess a final `x` is missing from the docs), which one can use to shorten the code. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-fu-0.2.7.7/docs/Data-Random.html#t:StdRandom

Comment: True, that's nicer. I couldn't find `sampleRVar` – it turns out to be called simply `sample` now; documentation a bit outdated...